# Exoplayer jar file

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm trying to import exoplayer library to my project but I get many errors, so I decided to add exoplayer as a jar file but the problem is I cannot find it in internet to download.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [ExoPlayer Github repository](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer), you must download the repository and build a jar manually. Full instructions can be found at the [Google Media Framework ad sample](https://github.com/googleads/google-media-framework-android#i-want-to-use-a-newer-version-of-exoplayer).

If you are using Gradle and Android Studio, however, you don't need to download the jar at all, instead using the [jcenter dependency](https://bintray.com/google/exoplayer/exoplayer/view):

```
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.4.1'
```

Comment: Thanks ,I followed Google Media Framework ad sample and the library has been added to my project successfully right now.

Comment: @ianhanniballake, my current configuration is eclipse without gradle etc... Is there a simple way to get that .jar file so that I import it in my project and I am good to go?

Comment: @user3793589 - after a year of deprecation, you should expect everything in Eclipse is much harder. Android Studio 2.0 is out now - maybe it is time to switch

Comment: I think it is time for the big move indeed. Thanks,