# Easy way to include third-party Views in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

When working with ExoPlayer in Android Studio, to add a PlayerView to my application's layout I always have to click on the "Text" tab and dive into the XML.

Is there a way to add such third-party views to the palette so I can drag and drop a PlayerView directly onto my layout?

### Update

Here's a screenshot of my Android Studio IDE. There's no "Project" tab or other clear means of adding to the palette

[image]

Comment: Eh, the designer is only good for learning the view properties, afterwards you have to write everything in XML to make it reliable anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I may have figured out the source of my issue. As I mentioned in the original question, I'm working with ExoPlayer.

First, [a View will only show up in the design palette if it's defined **either** in your project **or** in a JAR file](http://tools.android.com/recent/customviewsinthepalette)

Next, [ExoPlayer does not distribute a JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778796/exoplayer-jar-file)

When using jcenter to pull in ExoPlayer (as instructed by their installation guide) it will not build a JAR and so Android Studio is unaware of any custom views

Answer (score 1):

Palette has "Project" tab, hope this helps

[image]

Comment: Mine doesn't seem to have that tab. I'll amend my first post with a screenshot

Comment: After spending a few more days on this, I've figured out ***why*** I lack that tab, but not how to fix it. Android Studio will only display custom views if they extend the `View` class. The third-party library I've pulled in implements multiple custom views that extend the `FrameLayout` class. Is there any way to display these in the design view?